# Loading db.ListProperty() with AppEngine bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to populate a db.ListProperty() model field using bulkloader.

I'm using an import transform function as follows:

```
def parse_array(fn):
    def wrapper(value):
        return [fn(seg) for seg in re.split("\\,", value) if not seg=='']
   return wrapper
```

Configured as follows:

> > > import_transform: lib.bulkloader_helpers.parse_array(int)

Some of the arrays are empty, and these are causing a problem. When I upload:

> > > BadValueError: May not use the empty list as a property value; property xxx is [].

Uh oh. Okay, let's change the import transform function:

```
def parse_array(fn):
    def wrapper(value):
        args[fn(seg) for seg in re.split("\\,", value) if not seg=='']
        if args==[]:
            return None
        else:
            return args 
    return wrapper
```

Now the empty lists load just fine. However when the app tries to load the model:

> > > BadValueError: Property xxx is required

Nor can I set db.ListProperty(required=False):

> > > google.appengine.ext.db.ConfigurationError: required must be True.

Anyone suggest a way out ?

Thanks,

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug (Issue 3646)](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3646) with the App Engine development environment.

A workaround is to change (as of version 1.9.6) line 1530 of google.appengine.api.datastore_types.py which reads:

```
  if not values:
```

To:

```
  if not values_type is list and not values:
```

Afterwards you can properly insert

```
[]
```

for the empty arrays and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Google haven't fixed this yet (Feb 2013, API version 1.7.4), so here's a workaround that doesn't involve patching AppEngine code:

First use your updated import_transform function, that returns `None` instead of an empty list. Then add a `post_import_function` for the entity to your bulkloader.yaml ([docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Configuration_File_Reference_Details)) that checks list properties for `None` and deletes them from the entity, thereby setting them back to the empty list:

```
def post_import(input_dict, instance, bulkload_state_copy):
    if instance["list_prop_name"] is None:
        del instance["list_prop_name"]
    return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `required` argument altogether. If it's supplied, it must be set to `True`, but not supplying it makes it `False`.

Comment: I don't have a :required field. I tried setting it to False to see if that would help matters, but no luck. Any ideas why I can't return an empty list from my import_transform function ?

Comment: @Justin I don't see your model definition anywhere. Where is it?